# Маппинг переменных из appsettings.json в класс

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, settings, environment-variables

Я хочу смаппить настройки, описанные в `appsettings.json` в экземпляр класса настроек. Это легко сделать с помощью  `Get<T>()` или `Bind(obj)`, но есть одна проблема. Имена переменных в `appsettings.json` записаны в upper case, тогда как имена свойств класса настроек - в PascalCase. Для примера вот содержимое `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "FIELD_ONE": "foo",
    "FIELD_TWO": "bar"
}
```

и класс настроек:

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Как заставить `.NET` правильно и автоматически смаппить эти данные?
Пробовал сделать так, но не помогло

```
public class MySettings
{
     [JsonProperty("FIELD_ONE")]
     public string FieldOne { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("FIELD_TWO")]
     public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Какой сериализатор то? `System.Text.Json`? тогда аттрибут должен быть `JsonPropertyName`, а не `JsonProperty`. Не путайте сериализаторы, у них разные аттрибуты. А лучше вообще используйте один, а не два.

Comment: @aepot я пробовал оба сериализатора (майкрософтовский и Json.NET) каждый со своими родными атрибутами

Comment: @aepot - это не (де)сериализация, а использование [конфигураций](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#json-configuration-provider)

Comment: Вообще, то, что у вас в `appsetting.json` находятся такие поля - очень странно. Подумайте над тем, чтобы хранить такой файл отдельно, как `embedded resource` той сборки, где он должен использоваться

Answer (score 1):

Автоматически, скорее всего, никак.

Придётся делать вручную:

```
var mySettings = new MySettings();
var section = configurationRoot.GetSection("MySettings");

mySettings.FieldOne = section.GetValue<string>("FIELD_ONE");
mySettings.FieldTwo = section.GetValue<string>("FIELD_TWO");
```

Лучше всего, конечно, изменить имена ключей в конфиге, чтобы они совпадали с именами свойств в классе.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65789302/6468198 - можно и автоматически, но немного костыльно.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что хотелось бы не вручную, а автоматически.  Использовать совпадающие имена переменных не вариант по определённым причинам

Comment: @AndreiKhotko - я попробовал вариант с промежуточным словарём. Он работает лишь со строковыми (string) параметрами. А числа (int) сериализуются как строки в кавычках и при десериализации вылетает исключение. Но если у автора вопроса только строки, то вариант рабочий.

Comment: @Pupkin - нет у вас никаких определённых причин. Просто измените имена ключей в конфиге и всё. Делов на минуту. Время пошло!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov попробуйте приказывать тем, кто готов слушать ваши "советы".